# Spring Kafka consuming old messages which are already consumed by the consumer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i have a Spring boot application and using Spring Kafka. we have create a consumer which is consuming messages from 4 topics. these topics doesnt have any partition. the issue i am facing here a rendom behavior that out of three topics, in any one topic offset stop and my consumer keep on consuming same messages from that topic again and again until we need to manually move the offset to latest.below is the configuration YAML configuration i have :

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
   consumer:
      bootstrap-servers:  ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
      group-id: group_id
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
kafka:
  consumer:
    allTopicList: user.topic,student.topic,class.topic,teachers.topic**
```

as it is a Spring boot application, default offset is set to latest.
what i am doing wrong here, please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

You should set

```
...consumer:
     enable-auto-commit: false
```

The listener container will more reliably commit the offsets.

You should also consider

```
     ack-mode: RECORD
```

and the container will commit the offset for each successfully processed record (default is BATCH).

Comment: Thanks Gary, i am using  spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.1.7.RELEASE which is internally taking kafka-clients-2.0.1

Comment: If you can't upgrade to Boot 2.2, you should at least upgrade to Boot 2.1.13 which pulls in spring-kafka 2.2.12 (same kafka-clients 2.0.1).

Comment: Gary i made the changes but getting below  message in the log in one instance(out of two) of my application :                        Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 
This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies 
that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session 
timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Comment: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException

Comment: This means your code can't handle the records received by the poll quickly enough; you need to either decrease `max.poll.records` or increase `max.poll.interval.ms` (or both).

Comment: Gary, i made some chages in my application, now my topics have two partition, in one consumer, partition is assigned : KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [user.topic-0, class.topic-0, student.topic-0, teachers.topic-0] but in other consumer log i am seeing nothing is assigned : KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [] , . and all the partition are getting consumed by one consumer only .

Comment: Use the `kafka-topics.sh` command line (`--describe`) to make sure you really have two partitions in each topic. It makes no sense that only one partition is assigned.

Comment: Hi Gary, i have decided to go with 0 partition. now i am planning to use max.poll.records=10, enable-auto-commit: false , is there a way, i can process and commit records 1 by 1 so if 5 records out of 10 processed successfully then offset should move to fifth position. with  ack-mode: RECORD, commit is not happening for 5 successful processed records and its processing all the 10 records again.

Comment: That doesn't make sense; turn on DEBUG logging, or the `commitLogLevel` container property to see offset commit activity.